# Cristal Reports: How to place group summary values into another group's footer

Tags: crystal-reports

All!

I have a subreport in a form of a table. It is a list of rooms in a building with several types of areas for every room (in each row of the table) . Every room has a type as well. I need summarized data by room types in my report. But I need to place it not after each group (by room type), but in the end of the table. My report data grouped by room number and level number as well.  That is I have to move the summarized values from the room type group footer to the room number (parent of the room type group) group footer. And CR allows me to do that, but in the report I can see only the first summarized row.

I can not use cross tabs because they won't integrate into the main table seamlessly. I can get needed values with use of global variables and "WhilePrintingRecords". But again, how can I format these data to append it to the table seamlessly?

Is there a solution to the problem? If it can not be done in CR at all, please, tell me as well.

It looks like this now:

```
rooms of type 1  
1         areaval1     areaval2    areaval3  
2         areaval1     areaval2    areaval3  
3         areaval1     areaval2    areaval3  
Summary for type 1:  
GroupName sumval       sumval      sumval  
rooms of type 2  
4         areaval1     areaval2    areaval3  
5         areaval1     areaval2    areaval3  
Summary for type 2  
GroupName sumval       sumval      sumval  

And this is what I need:  
rooms of type 1  
1     areaval1     areaval2    areaval3  
2     areaval1     areaval2    areaval3  
3     areaval1     areaval2    areaval3  
rooms of type 2  
4     areaval1     areaval2    areaval3  
5     areaval1     areaval2    areaval3  
Summary for type 1  
GroupName sumval       sumval      sumval  
Summary for type 2  
GroupName sumval       sumval      sumval
```

In the real report it is formatted as a table, with visible lines and all... This is the problem - to save the moved part as part of the table.

Comment: Hey there, please try to be more specific so that we can answer your question. Can you show us an example of the data and what format you expect in the end?

Comment: Yes this can be done in Crystal but as @vektor mentioned, you need to provide more detail. An example might be helpful. Will there be a known number of room types? That's a big question when considering a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its definitely possible but you need to do a bit of hard work.

I believe you have created room number group as a parent group to room type, So in room number group header create a String array and assign it null as below.

Create a formula `Initialize`

```
Shared Stringvar array store;
store:="";
```

Now in group2 footer (room type group) where you have summary data for group footer create a variable and write below code:

Create a formula `add data`

```
Shared Stringvar array store;

store:=store+ (CSTR(GroupName)+"-"+CSTR(sumval)+"-"+CSTR(sumval)+"-"+CSTR(sumval);
```

In group footer 1 you need to extract the array to display the data:

Create a formula `Extract Data`

```
Shared Stringvar array store;

    Split(store[1],"-")[1] + "    "+Split(store[1],"-")[2] + "    "++Split(store[1],"-")[3] + "    "+Split(store[1],"-")[4] + "    "+ChrW(13)+
    Split(store[2],"-")[1] + "    "+Split(store[2],"-")[2] + "    "++Split(store[2],"-")[3] + "    "+Split(store[2],"-")[4] + "    "+ChrW(13)
//This will depend on number of sub groups, If there are more sub groups let me know will try to automate
```

At present I don't have tool to test but this will work, Implement and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is what I meant when I said -

> I can get needed values with use of global variables and "WhilePrintingRecords". But again, how can I format these data to append it to the table seamlessly?

Yes, this will work. But what about formatting?

[This is what I need (well, the report is in Russian):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJ8j5.jpg)

The rows, which I talk about, are in the red rectangle.
The number of room types is variable.

Answer (score 0):

No further suggestions? Was not I still clear enough?
Well, I have tried to solve the problem modifying a data source for the report (a XML file). I put the  summary values into the XML file instead of summarizing in the report, and tried to get them from there.
But there is another problem.
I already use a subreport for the room areas table (there is a lot of information in the report besides the table and using subreport here is the only way). So I can not use another subreport to put the summary table into. If to put it to a group footer, then I still can see only the first row. If to put it in a subreport of the main report, then it appears after the whole table, not after a needed group as I need.

What can I do here?